# a way to parse S3 data array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, amazon-s3

If, for example, I had array like this:

```
array(34) {
  ["ahostel.lt/img/background.png"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(29) "ahostel.lt/img/background.png"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1277819688)
    ["size"]=>
    int(36811)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "2600e98e10aba543fb2637b701dec4f3"
  }
  ["ahostel.lt/img/body-navigation-bg.png"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(37) "ahostel.lt/img/body-navigation-bg.png"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1277819688)
    ["size"]=>
    int(409)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "2e8743f24d46748c5919dfa44b51c2a5"
  }
  ["ahostel.lt/img/calendar-input.gif"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(33) "ahostel.lt/img/calendar-input.gif"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1277819688)
    ["size"]=>
    int(630)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "45d5148e7937fc75a530d7ceb73b7bc8"
  }
  ["ahostel.lt/img/facebook-icon.png"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(32) "ahostel.lt/img/facebook-icon.png"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1277819688)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1090)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "8a76e313b097f53d0f225a5db6f9ae6b"
  }
  ["ahostel.lt/img/favicon.png"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "ahostel.lt/img/favicon.png"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1277819689)
    ["size"]=>
    int(505)
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "daa5091eb2c059fc36b54d521e589a50"
  }
[...]
```

What would be the best sollution to get all directories and files (in separate arrays, though) from a path *ahostel.lt/img/*. I now have many foreach cycles and this does not look like going towards a good solution.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to extract the file names or do you want to split the path to get the directory or do you want to retrieve the actual files?

Comment: I want to get an array like this, however, with the information about files in *ahostel.lt/img/* path only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files          = array();
$directories    = array();

foreach($this->file_system as $key => $file_object_info)
{
    // make sure this is the requested path and exclude it from appearaning twice
    if(strpos($key, $path) === 0 && $key !== $path)
    {
        $relative_path  = mb_substr($key, mb_strlen($path));

        // this is a file
        if(strpos($relative_path, '/') === FALSE)
        {
            $files[$key]        = $file_object_info;
        }
        // this is a directory
        elseif(!substr($relative_path, strpos($relative_path, '/') + 1))
        {
            $directories[$key]  = $file_object_info;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is the farest I can optimize it. It isn't as bad as I though it will be, though.